# Building SOAP Web Service API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, web-services, soap

I have to write APIs using SOAP as a protocol. I was trying to figure out what the best solution is nowadays.
As authentication I would need basic http authentication.

I was looking at the possibilities regarding .NET (I'm open to other frameworks anyway).

I saw that there are two projects for .NET Core:

- SoapCor, https://github.com/DigDes/SoapCor
- CoreWCF, https://github.com/CoreWCF/CoreWCF

As for .NET I found:

- WCF
- ASMX

I wanted to understand which was the easiest way, if there are other services in .NET (or even other frameworks) considering that I am only interested in exposing SOAP endpoints with HTTP Basic Authentication

Comment: If you'd joined a developing team, then I don't think you need to consider to user soap or some other options exception you are the one who play the role of architect, but ... and actually I jus t want to say, if you want to build an asp.net core application, for example .net 6, then when you create a new .net 6 project in visual studio, you can see the default template will provide you some api... I think that is the normal option for most of the developers. then here is a [blog](https://smartbear.com/blog/soap-vs-rest-whats-the-difference/) which I think will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think your question is a good and sound one, however it is not on topic enough for stackoverflow; I mean the answer will be subjective and opinionated. So my advice is to check this with your development team or organisation. Maybe there are some operations aspects to consider as well? If it entirely up you the try the different flavors and pick the one you like the most!? *That is my subjective and opinionated answer!*